# What "basic account information" is "viewed" by a Google Drive app via auth scopes?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have read all the information and guidance and watched the videos on

- Developers Google Drive (sorry, I do not have enough "reputation points" to include all the links that would be relevant here).
- as well as Google Privacy Policies.

In the list of Google Drive auth scopes, which ones are covered by the permissions request to users for the app to "view basic account information"?

https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes

I can only find examples, rather than a complete list.

I am also trying to understand how this relates to the Privacy Policy, ie. whether this "basic account information" is "Personal Information" or "Google Account" information.

http://www.google.com/intl/en-GB/policies/privacy/key-terms/#toc-terms-personal-info

> ### Personal information
>
> This is information which you provide to us which personally
> identifies you, such as your name, email address or billing
> information, or other data which can be reasonably linked to such
> information by Google.
>
> ### Google Account
>
> You may access some of our services by signing up for a Google Account
> and providing us with some personal information (typically, your name,
> email address and a password). This account information will be used
> to authenticate you when you access Google services and protect your
> account from unauthorised access by others. You can edit or terminate
> your account at any time through your Google Account settings.

I have read elsewhere that the "basic account information" is not actually "viewed", ie. visible to, the app developer but is instead transmitted in encrypted form for use by the app.

(I am not an app developer - this just seems to be the only place where there are Google staff watching and answering these sorts of questions).

Answer (score 3):

User's profile and email is available if you grant access for the following scopes:

- profile: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
- email: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Profile stands for a Google Account and contains user's ID, name, photo, URL, country, language, timezone, and birthdate.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly Burcu! :-)

So, just to make sure I have got it right, the "Basic Account Information" that is referred to in the "permission" request is:

1) User's ID
2) User's name
3) User's Google Account Profile Photo
4) url (of the user's public profile?)
5) Country
6) Language
7) Timezone
8) Birthdate

As you can see, the only one I am unsure about is the "url".

Best wishes,

Comment: @Liz, yes you can retrieve them all once you got a permission for userinfo.profile scope. Url is user's personal homepage if he/she set one.